# Estimote Beacon Accelerometer update time

Tags: ios, ibeacon, estimote

i used beacon accelerometer, but accelerometer count data is given only when beacon is stabilized. for example "shaking beacon along 5 minutes and stop" is equal only 1 count.
So, can't i count step with beacon ?

thanks

Comment: Can you explain how you try to use beacon? Beacons are only transmitters, they couldn't detect motion.

Comment: [accelerometer estimote](http://blog.estimote.com/post/81380655308/estimote-sdk-updated-with-accelerometer-and-temperature). i hope i could teach you sth.@BoranA

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in the link that you send.

> When beacon is moving it is not sending
>   beacon:accelerometerStateChanged delegate method. Wait few seconds
>   after each shake.

[image]

So you need to stop for few seconds to get data.

Answer (score 1):

Estimote Beacons can determine whether they're in motion or in standstill. So technically it is possible to count each time a specific beacon was put in motion. However if your aim is counting steps, then there's a big margin of error that has to be into consideration. Generally turning a beacon into a step counter probably isn't the most fortunate use case. After all, you can use phone's accelerometer for that - and even with a beacon in your pocket you still need the smartphone to receive signal and count steps.

Cheers.